# Onclick to add layer from geojson file

Tags: leaflet

I currently get to a point where I add a layer to the big cities layer (first layer) from a geojson file and zoom in it.
My aim now is when I click on the first layer, another layer should appear for small cities and it is name cities also.

The geojson file has both layer 1 and 2. To know which layer - if name_1==name_2 then it is layer 1 else layer 2

I need help as it is my first project in leaflet .

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>
            My Map
        </title>
        <!-- Leaflet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="data/muhafzat.geojson"></script>
        <script src="data/data.geojson"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #map { height : 400px; }
            .legend { background : white; line-height : 1.5em}
            .legend i { width : 5em; float : left }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Map</h1>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>


            function getCountryColor(popEst){
                if(popEst > 100000000){
                    return 'red';
                }else if(popEst > 50000000){
                    return 'blue';
                }else{
                    return 'green';
                }
            }

            function countriesStyle(feature){
                return {
                    fillColor : getCountryColor(feature.properties.pop_est),
                    weight : 2,
                    opacity : 1,
                    color : 'white',
                    dashArray : 3,
                    fillOpacity : 0.7
                }
            }
             var popmaps = function(feature,layer){
                        var popUp = feature.properties.name
                        layer.bindPopup(String(popUp));
                    }


            var map = L.map('map').setView([43.8476, 18.3564], 13);//Sets the view of the map (geographical center and zoom) with the given animation options.
            var countriesLayer = L.geoJson(
                countries,
                {style : countriesStyle},{
                               pointToLayer:function (feature, latlng) {
                               return L.marker(latlng, {

                                                     fillColor: "#000000",
                                                     color: "green",

                                                     opacity: 1,

                                                     });
                               },
                               onEachFeature:popmaps
                               }).addTo(map);

            L.geoJSON(countries,{
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                    return L.circleMarker(name ,geojsonMarkerOptions);
                }
            }).addTo(map);

            map.fitBounds(countriesLayer.getBounds());//in order to cover the whole canvas

            countriesLayer.on("click", function (event) {//in order to zoom in each layer
                // Assuming the clicked feature is a shape, not a point marker.
                map.fitBounds(event.layer.getBounds());
            });

            var legend = L.control({position : 'bottomright'});
            legend.onAdd = function(map){
                var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend');
                var labels = [
                    "Population greater than 100000000", 
                    "Population greater than 50000000", 
                    "Population equal or less than 50000000"
                ];


                        var grades = [100000001, 50000001, 50000000];
                div.innerHTML = '<div><b>Legend</b></div>';
                for(var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
                    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background:' 
                    + getCountryColor(grades[i]) + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                    + labels[i] + '<br />';
                }
                return div;
            }
            legend.addTo(map);
        </script>

        <div id='buttons'>

        <input type="button" id="l1" value="layer one" onclick="alert('layer one');msgr(); "/>
        <input type="button" id="l2" value="layer two" onclick="dofunction();"/>
        <input type="button" id="l3" value="layer three" onclick="dofunction(); "/>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

My GeoJSON file looks like :

```
var countries ={
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID_0": 116, "ISO": "JOR", "NAME_0": "Jordan", "ID_1": 1, "NAME_1": "Ajlun", "ID_2": 1, "NAME_2": "Ajloun", "HASC_2": "JO.AJ.AJ", "CCN_2": 0, "CCA_2": null, "TYPE_2": "Nahia", "ENGTYPE_2": "Sub-Province", "NL_NAME_2": null, "VARNAME_2": "Ajlun" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 35.709953308105526, 32.386882781982479 ], [ 35.721813201904297, 32.384082794189567 ], [ 35.737407684326115, 32.381393432617187 ], [ 35.740989685058594, 32.380111694335994 ], [ 35.746570587158203, 32.376800537109375 ], [ 35.750656127929631, 32.375484466552848 ], [ 35.755344390869141, 32.374767303466797 ], [ 35.760337829589957, 32.374446868896541 ], [ 35.767951965332088, 32.374534606933651 ], [ 35.772846221923942, 32.375022888183707 ], [ 35.777328491211051, 32.376033782959098 ], [ 35.779300689697322, 32.376819610595817 ], [ 35.786537170410156, 32.381053924560547 ], [ 35.794475555419922, 32.383533477783203 ], [ 35.798202514648438, 32.38510894775402 ], [ 35.805011749267635, 32.389827728271484 ], [ 35.820453643798885, 32.397651672363338 ], [ 35.827964782714844, 32.401065826415959 ], [ 35.835235595703182, 32.405872344970703 ], [ 35.840755462646598, 32.404201507568416 ], [ 35.849449157714957, 32.400852203369254 ], [ 35.859226226806754, 32.398956298828182 ], [ 35.872241973877067, 32.397621154785213 ], [ 35.88483810424799, 32.399063110351506 ], [ 35.889312744140739, 32.399990081787109 ], [ 35.893348693847656, 32.401485443115234 ], [ 35.898902893066406, 32.405239105224723 ], [ 35.910152435302848, 32.411609649658203 ], [ 35.922111511230582, 32.420455932617187 ], [ 35.923290252685604, 32.402427673339901 ], [ 35.924568176269645, 32.391437530517635 ], [ 35.925888061523551, 32.386489868164063 ], [ 35.928176879882926, 32.382293701171875 ], [ 35.932826995849666, 32.377632141113338 ], [ 35.946205139160156, 32.369243621826172 ], [ 35.955009460449276, 32.365921020507813 ], [ 35.959201812744254, 32.363773345947322 ], [ 35.960937500000057, 32.362270355224666 ], [ 35.967174530029354, 32.354835510253906 ], [ 35.955650329589957, 32.348663330078239 ], [ 35.950786590576286, 32.344406127929744 ], [ 35.945461273193473, 32.340801239013615 ], [ 35.941913604736328, 32.337791442871207 ], [ 35.938816070556584, 32.335971832275504 ], [ 35.928977966308707, 32.332870483398551 ], [ 35.919715881347656, 32.327957153320312 ], [ 35.908443450927848, 32.325328826904411 ], [ 35.903789520263672, 32.323863983154297 ], [ 35.889163970947322, 32.317707061767692 ], [ 35.885223388671932, 32.3155517578125 ], [ 35.883338928222713, 32.314140319824332 ], [ 35.880100250244141, 32.310871124267578 ], [ 35.877803802490234, 32.307037353515682 ], [ 35.873989105224609, 32.294704437255859 ], [ 35.869277954101676, 32.284889221191463 ], [ 35.868049621582088, 32.280391693115234 ], [ 35.865505218505916, 32.264183044433707 ], [ 35.863887786865234, 32.259944915771484 ], [ 35.85990142822277, 32.252243041992188 ], [ 35.856620788574276, 32.242519378662223 ], [ 35.854736328125057, 32.239189147949332 ], [ 35.845932006835994, 32.230449676513729 ], [ 35.840759277343807, 32.226772308349609 ], [ 35.837230682373104, 32.223606109619197 ], [ 35.834396362304631, 32.221618652343807 ], [ 35.820922851562557, 32.214927673339901 ], [ 35.810604095459098, 32.210945129394645 ], [ 35.805030822753906, 32.208404541015682 ], [ 35.799484252929631, 32.205989837646484 ], [ 35.786060333251953, 32.201190948486328 ], [ 35.783786773681641, 32.209152221679688 ], [ 35.783321380615348, 32.213363647460994 ], [ 35.784141540527401, 32.219768524169979 ], [ 35.786071777343807, 32.224590301513786 ], [ 35.787792205810547, 32.232173919677791 ], [ 35.792560577392578, 32.247150421142521 ], [ 35.794258117675838, 32.250358581542969 ], [ 35.797103881835994, 32.253665924072266 ], [ 35.798732757568416, 32.256496429443303 ], [ 35.799480438232479, 32.260040283203125 ], [ 35.79913330078125, 32.263755798339901 ], [ 35.797370910644645, 32.267311096191406 ], [ 35.796089172363281, 32.268619537353572 ], [ 35.793090820312557, 32.270637512207088 ], [ 35.783493041992188, 32.275585174560547 ], [ 35.779201507568359, 32.277057647705192 ], [ 35.775104522705135, 32.277946472167912 ], [ 35.767448425292912, 32.278743743896541 ], [ 35.760246276855469, 32.277339935302734 ], [ 35.755218505859489, 32.275367736816463 ], [ 35.748241424560661, 32.270988464355526 ], [ 35.736751556396541, 32.266860961914176 ], [ 35.729312896728572, 32.262603759765682 ], [ 35.715927124023551, 32.258949279785213 ], [ 35.704689025878849, 32.254459381103516 ], [ 35.700469970703239, 32.253166198730469 ], [ 35.685756683349609, 32.249370574951229 ], [ 35.667037963867244, 32.245250701904297 ], [ 35.671630859375057, 32.254451751708984 ], [ 35.674545288086051, 32.261421203613281 ], [ 35.675868988037166, 32.266059875488338 ], [ 35.677940368652457, 32.277114868164119 ], [ 35.679145812988281, 32.281028747558594 ], [ 35.683525085449162, 32.287788391113338 ], [ 35.685024261474666, 32.291553497314567 ], [ 35.688076019287166, 32.311332702636662 ], [ 35.689579010009766, 32.315082550048828 ], [ 35.693088531494197, 32.320110321044979 ], [ 35.694602966308594, 32.323894500732479 ], [ 35.695453643798828, 32.328216552734432 ], [ 35.697509765625, 32.347080230713004 ], [ 35.701675415039063, 32.360050201416129 ], [ 35.706249237060604, 32.372310638427734 ], [ 35.709953308105526, 32.386882781982479 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID_0": 116, "ISO": "JOR", "NAME_0": "Jordan", "ID_1": 1, "NAME_1": "Ajlun", "ID_2": 2, "NAME_2": "Kofranjah", "HASC_2": "JO.AJ.KF", "CCN_2": 0, "CCA_2": null, "TYPE_2": "Nahia", "ENGTYPE_2": "Sub-Province", "NL_NAME_2": null, "VARNAME_2": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 35.742671966552791, 32.169574737548828 ], [ 35.733383178710994, 32.174312591552734 ], [ 35.72740554809576, 32.177928924560547 ], [ 35.722118377685661, 32.181858062744254 ], [ 35.713947296142521, 32.189167022705021 ], [ 35.70883941650402, 32.194160461425895 ], [ 35.702774047851676, 32.201755523681584 ], [ 35.697807312011832, 32.205844879150447 ], [ 35.693527221679744, 32.210323333740348 ], [ 35.687484741211051, 32.215686798095703 ], [ 35.677803039550724, 32.228816986084098 ], [ 35.667037963867244, 32.245250701904297 ], [ 35.685756683349609, 32.249370574951229 ], [ 35.700469970703239, 32.253166198730469 ], [ 35.704689025878849, 32.254459381103516 ], [ 35.715927124023551, 32.258949279785213 ], [ 35.729312896728572, 32.262603759765682 ], [ 35.736751556396541, 32.266860961914176 ], [ 35.748241424560661, 32.270988464355526 ], [ 35.755218505859489, 32.275367736816463 ], [ 35.760246276855469, 32.277339935302734 ], [ 35.767448425292912, 32.278743743896541 ], [ 35.775104522705135, 32.277946472167912 ], [ 35.779201507568359, 32.277057647705192 ], [ 35.783493041992188, 32.2755851745]] ] } }
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example has been given on the leaflet original website

> http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

If you use it and implement your logic of geojson instead of markers you can acheive said objective